# Bash running complex command on remote server

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to run this command remotely with ssh:

```
remote_command="fname=$(echo $(basename $(ls /opt/jboss/standalone/deployments/*.ear))); mv /opt/jboss/standalone/deployments/${fname}.undeployed /opt/jboss/standalone/deployments/${fname}.dodeploy"
```

This command redeploys the ear file on the remote server (if the ear file with an .undeploy extension exists). There is only one ear.

The remote_command variable is passed to a function responsible to run the var remote_command:

```
function run_remote_command() { 
  local command=$1
  local output=$(sshpass -pPassw ssh user@host_ip '$command' 2>&1)
}
```

The call to the function is

```
run_remote_command $remote_command
```

When I run the main script, the execution of the remote command is done: 
var fname gets assigned the value of the ear filename. 
But then $fname is empty when it is executed with mv.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Best regards,

Alain

Answer (score 4):

Because you're not properly quoting the command, your **local** shell is expanding `$fname`

```
function run_remote_command() { 
  local command=$1
  # must double quote the command here
  sshpass -pPassw ssh user@host_ip "$command"
}

# must use single quotes here. newlines added for clarity
remote_command='
  root=/opt/jboss/standalone/deployments
  ear_files=($root/*.ear)
  if [[ "${ear_files[0]}" ]]; then 
    fname=$(basename "${ear_files[0]}") 
    mv "$root/${fname}.undeployed" "$root/${fname}.dodeploy"
  fi
'

# must double quote the command here
run_remote_command "$remote_command"
```

I'm assuming your shell on the remote end is bash.